# How to mock MuleEventContext class

Tags: unit-testing, mule

I want to test my own custom class `Group` which implements `org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable`. `Group` implements `onCall(MuleEventContext)` method. Now to test `Group`, I need to `mock` `MuleEventContext` class.

I am interested to know how people are doing this and if they can throw some best practices/tricks and tips,

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to implement `org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable`? If your component was a POJO you would not have to mess with the `MuleEventContext`.

If you really need it, then use the `getTestEventContext` helpers from http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/testapidocs/index.html?org/mule/tck/junit4/AbstractMuleContextTestCase.html

Or, if you need extra infrastructure like the `MuleClient`, then actually create a functional test case by extending http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/tck/junit4/FunctionalTestCase.html

Comment: yes I need to implement `Callable` to get message properties and `client` from mule context

Comment: so how can I set the `MuleMessage` using the API you provided. I am using Mule3.3

Comment: reviewed my answer, which also applies for 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Use AbstractMuleContextTestCase.  This should solve the problem.

Make the testcase extend AbstractMuleContextTestCase.

Then in the test method to get the object of MuleEventContet use the getTestEventContext method of the
 MuleTestUtils helper calss provided by mule.

```
MyComponentTest extends  AbstractMuleContextTestCase {
```

Then in the test method :

```
    MuleEventContext eventContext = MuleTestUtils.getTestEventContext("",      MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, muleContext);            
        .........
        ......... 
    MuleMessage result = (MuleMessage)componentInstance.onCall(eventContext);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is my favorite way to create a MuleEventContext for testing a Callable component:

```
class TestClass extends org.mule.munit.runner.functional.FunctionalMunitSuite {
...
    MuleEvent event = testEvent("PAYLOAD HERE");
    MuleEventContext eventContext = new org.mule.DefaultMuleEventContext(event);
...
}
```